# Why manipulating an UI control requires to be done within the thread in which it was created?

Tags: c#, android, .net, user-interface, controls

I have been developing many softwares using C# .NET and Android. I have noticed that both systems have the same behaviour on `Thread` upon UI `control` (Label/TextView, etc...). And for that, I don't think it is just coincident for the design to prevent changes outside of thread.

The most popular problem people are having is that they cannot be changed (say, `Text` property) outside of the thread they were created. We must either use `Invoke` in C#, or use `Handler` in Android.

My question is, **WHY** do controls have to implement such behaviour? What bad may happen if I could change their property/field outside of the thread they were created?

**EDIT:** Thanks *Raghunandanless* for your reference. I have already known parts of it, and my main concern for this question is, why ***thread from a thread pool aren't running on your UI thread*** cannot access control's properties/fields? The Android's `View` are actually just POJO, am I correct? If so, I think any thread can access them with no problem. Please clarify if I said anything wrong.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/multiple-threads/communicate-ui.html for android. Quoting from docs "tasks that you run on a thread from a thread pool aren't running on your UI thread, they don't have access to UI objects. To move data from a background thread to the UI thread, use a Handler that's running on the UI thread."

Comment: @Raghunandan Edited my question.
And I also hope someone can tell if .NET also have the same reason or not.

Comment: Concurrency is hard. Thread-safe implementation of user controls will introduce performance overhead, while concurrent access isn't required in most of the scenarios.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the same reason collections are non-synchronized by default in most standard libraries:

1. because most of the time you naturally work within single thread and wan't pay synchronization price
2. it is not enough to syncronize widget's methods, because to atomically update two related widgets you have to first lock both. But if you do it, then synchronized methods are just waste of code and time.